# changing css but the change doesn't applied on website

Tags: php, css, laravel, cpanel

I was changing a few files ( using both FTP or Cpanel file editor ) on Cpanel. At first, the changes I was making to the CSS HTML files were being shown on my site, but now they are not. I have cleared my browser cache, restarted my computer, used an incognito window. Nothing is helping. I even asked my CPANEL support, they said there is an issue with my .htpaccess file, but I can't even see that final anywhere on my file manager let alone edit it. I am doing basic edits on CSS (font size changes, alignment, etc) so I don't know if there is an issue with the coding?

Comment: You should check your css file in the browser (in most browsers ``F12`` to open the console). There you can check out if the css file contains your changes or not. If not it's probably your cache. If there are changes your css file is wrong.

Comment: @miile7 thanks for the help but, I tried many alternatives trying change CSS file to a new one, using incognito mode clearing cache but nothing changed, I even deleted all file of live website and upload  the ones I changed but nothing happens

Comment: Why is this tagged as `laravel`? Are you using Laravel? If you are, then depending on your env settings it could be caching the view files in `storage/framework/cache`. Try deleting those.

Comment: PS - this is another reason to do development work locally instead of on a remote server using FTP.

Comment: Did you solve your problem @tinox

Comment: yeah @waterloomatt am using laravel but on shared hosting and i deleted cache already but nothing changed

Comment: @Pie no I didn't sir, still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making changes to the CSS file, go to the browser and hit control shift r for a hard restart. This will eliminate the cache and use your updated changes.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things that can cause this.

Firstly try `ctrl + F5` which clears the cache when reloading. Web browsers cache data like styling to speed up load times.

Next if you still don't notice a difference, view the source of the live code and open the css file. In there you can verify the code is updated, if not you haven't uploaded it properly.

Since you're host mentioned your `.htaccess` file, I'll give you a quick tip. On cPanel file manager, click settings and enable dotfiles to be shown which will allow you to see it. the `.htaccess` file could be the culprit to server side caching which would explain nothing happening on restart. If that's the issue you need to contact your provider asking what server side caching software is in use and what can you do to disable it.

Once fully developed remember to turn it back on for extra site performance.

Comment: _"I have cleared my browser cache, restarted my computer, used an incognito window. Nothing is helping. "_

Comment: I have to be very generic with the answer of the question so it will benefit more people in future who face a similar site not updating issue.

Comment: There are thousands of questions like this on SO. We don't need another unless it has some groundbreaking new problem.

Comment: I'm not the one asking the question... just chill. I'm trying to help the OP while providing info for other people who stumble upon this ok? Am I being too nice by providing more info?

Comment: @tinox Did it work? If so please mark my answer as solved

Comment: @tinox We're the files on the webserver the updated ones? Remember to check by viewing source and clicking the .CSS link

Comment: You should look into cache-busting. It is deleting the cache. @tinox

Comment: cache-busting ? how Sir @Pie?